# Pseudo element on Div click not passed to button

Tags: asp.net, css, image, html

I have to show image with text in ASP.NET site. To do so I have overrided button render to add a div tag around button and the result is like following.

```
<div class="wrapper  cmd_save" id="_PageTemplate_innerHolder_btnsave_div">

<input name="_PageTemplate$innerHolder$btnsave value="Save" onclick="alert('hi');" id="_PageTemplate_innerHolder_btnsave" tabindex="5" class="cmd_base" type="submit">

</div>


.cmd_base
{
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 85px;
    z-index: 50;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);/* IE6-9 */
}

div.wrapper 
{
   display: inline;
    position:relative; 
    height:16px;
    background:transparent;
}

div.wrapper:after 
{
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    background:url('../_images/my_sprite.png') ; 
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:8px; 
    width:20px; 
    height:22px;
}

div.cmd_search:after
{
   background-position:-120px -8px;
}.


.cmd_base
{
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 85px;
    z-index: 50;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);/* IE6-9 */
}

div.wrapper 
{
   display: inline;
    position:relative; 
    height:16px;
    background:transparent;
}

div.wrapper:after 
{
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    background:url('../_images/my_sprite.png') ; 
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:8px; 
    width:20px; 
    height:22px;
}

div.cmd_search:after
{
   background-position:-120px -8px;
}
```

It is working very fine and look is also very good. But only issue is when I click on image it does call click of button inside Div. Any help on this.

Comment: Do you want a button that won't be clicked?

Comment: ... so... put the `onclick` attribute on the div?? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kuzgun I want the button to be clicked.

Comment: @BillyMathews Actually it is a asp.net button which at places have only server side event attached so in that case a javascript might not help.

Comment: Can you send an image or fiddle because that thing looks like hard to visualise for us.

Comment: Please check out [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/), it will help SO help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for our help. I just added pointer-events: none; in the pseudo class of the Div and it is working now. Click events are getting passed to the button.

```
div.wrapper:after 
{
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    background:url('../_images/my_sprite.png') ; 
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:8px; 
    width:20px; 
    height:22px;
pointer-events: none;
}
```